# Wordpress tinymce dialog box Body Element & Attribute Formal Documentation

Tags: wordpress, styles, tinymce, window-managers

I am new to the tinymce.  I have been trying to figure out all of the attributes I need to use to create decent looking dialog that the user fills out and create shortcode output. In the code example below the label and the textbox are butted against each other with no margin or padding and any trailing spaces in the label text are trimmed, this is just one change that I would like to make.  I have looked at the documentation to tinymce and all I find are simple brief code examples.

My Question 1: Where can I find the formal full documentation of this windowManager.open method and all of the possible attributes and methods associated with it?

My Question 2&3: Are these attribute actually native javascript? If so where can I find the formal full documentation to it?

Thanks for any help you can give me to retrieve the documentation or possibly formatting with a css sytle sheet (w/.mce-widget or .mce-textbox) and where and how to register this style sheet in Wordpress.

```
(function() {

    tinymce.create("tinymce.plugins.youtube_plugin", {

        //url argument holds the absolute url of our plugin directory
        init : function(ed, url) {
             alert('in youtube');

            //add new button     
            ed.addButton("youtube_button", {
                title : "Youtube Video Responsive Embed",
                cmd : "youtube_command",
                image : "https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/social-flat-rounded-rects/512/youtube_v2-32.png"
            });

            //button functionality.
            ed.addCommand("youtube_command", function() {
                //alert('hello youtube');
                ed.windowManager.open({
                    title: "YouTube Video Settings",   //    The title of the dialog window.
                    //file : url + '/../html/youtube.html',
                    width : 800,
                    height : 300,
                    inline : 1,
                    body: [{
                        type: 'container',
                        //label  : 'flow',
                        //layout: 'flow',
                        items: [
                        {type: 'label', text: 'Youtube ServerPath:'},
                        {type: 'textbox', size: '80', name: 'title', value: 'http://www.youtube.com/embed/'},
                        //{type: 'label', text: 'and two labels'}
                        ]
                    }],
                    buttons: [{
                          text: 'Submit',
                          onclick: 'submit'
                       }, {
                          text: 'Cancel',
                          onclick: 'close'
                       }],
                    onsubmit: function(e) {
                        //form = $('#youtube_plugin_id iframe').contents().find('form');
                        alert('hello');
                        ed.insertContent('Title: ' + e.data.title);
                    }
                });
                //var selected_text = ed.selection.getContent();
               // var return_text = "<span style='color: green'>" + selected_text + "</span>";
                //ed.execCommand("mceInsertContent", 0, return_text);
            });

        } // end init
    }); // end tinymce.create

    tinymce.PluginManager.add("youtube_button_plugin", tinymce.plugins.youtube_plugin);
})();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I didn't find any formal documentation to create a nice looking mce dialog box specifically, I did figure out how to format the dialog title and then embed an external html file that you can add a link tag to a css style sheet and the sky is the limit.

Here is the JavaScript code for the mce, it's up to you to create the external html and css files.

```
(function($) {
    /**
    This tinymce plugin provides the editor button and the modal dialog used to embed. 
    */
    //  Extract data stored in the global namespace in tinymce-dev-starter.php.
    var passed_data = lgrriw_data;
    var php_version = passed_data.php_version;
    var valid_domains = passed_data.valid_domains;
    var dialogTitle = 'My Dialog Title';




    //  Define the TinyMCE plugin and setup the button.
    //  The last property in the first tinymce.create paramenter below must be the same
    //  as the plugin you defined in tinymce-dev-starter.php. In this case, it is
    //  lgrriw_plugin.  If we called it my_cool_plugin, the first parameter would change
    //  to 'tinymce.plugins.my_cool_plugin'.
    tinymce.create('tinymce.plugins.lgrriw_plugin', {
        init: function(editor, url) {
           /**
             * The editor parameter contains the TinyMCE editor instance.  The url
             * parameter contains the absolute url to the directory containing the
             * TinyMCE plugin file (this file's directory).
             *
             * We will be using editor to talk to the TinyMCE instance.  And we
             * will be using url to tell TinyMCE where files are (e.g. button
             * images).
             */
            //  Specify button properties and commands.
            //  The first parameter of editor.addButton must be the button ID
            //  given in tinymce-dev-starter.php. In this case, it is lgrriw_button.
            editor.addButton('lgrriw_button', {
                title: dialogTitle,   // Tooltip when hovering over button.
                image: url + '/../../assets/tinymce-button_32.png',    // The image for the button.
                cmd: 'lgrriw_command'                           // The editor command to execute on button click.
            });

            //  Define the "command" executed on button click.
            editor.addCommand('lgrriw_command', function() {
                editor.windowManager.open(
                    {
                        title: dialogTitle,   //    The title of the dialog window.
                        file:  url + '/../html/tinymce_dialog.html', //    The HTML file with the dialog contents links to css style sheet(s).
                        width: 810,                               //    The width of the dialog
                        height: 505,                              //    The height of the dialog
                        inline: 1                                 //    Whether to use modal dialog instead of separate browser window.
                    },

                    //  Parameters and arguments we want available to the window.
                    {
                        editor: editor,
                        jquery: $,
                        valid_domains: valid_domains
                    }
                );

                $('.mce-title').each(function(index,item){
                    // Iterate through the mce titles until you find
                    // the dialog for this dialog before formatting, otherwise
                    // the formatting will change the Wordpress
                    // Theme globally.  Be Careful!
                    if($(item).text() == dialogTitle){
                        // Format the dialog title using css
                        $(item).css('text-align', 'center');
                        $(item).css('color', '#336999');
                        $(item).css('background-color', '#add9ff');
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    });


    // Add the plugin to TinyMCE
    // Documentation: http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/api4:method.tinymce.AddOnManager.add
    tinymce.PluginManager.add('lgrriw_plugin', tinymce.plugins.lgrriw_plugin);
})(jQuery);
```